# separating columns within a div for left alignment of text (bootstrap)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, wrapper

i'm thinking this will be simple, but i cant get my head round it!

The main "Lorem Ipsum" text paragraph in the screenshot i would like to only fill the left half of the box that its in. When i try and put a div within the main div to do this, it aligns left but the box doesn't expand downwards with the text so it "over spills".

Screenshot
http://i772.photobucket.com/albums/yy4/philbuckthorpe/Screen%20Shot%202016-09-26%20at%2020.51.00_zpshcjcm6qh.png

```css
.thumbnail {
    padding: 0;
}

.thumbnail .caption-full {
    padding: 9px;
    color: #333;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">

        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-md-3">
                <p class="lead">Our Artists</p>
                <div class="list-group">
                    <a href="#" class="list-group-item active">Artist 1</a>
                    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Artist 2</a>
                    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Artist 3</a>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-9">

                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/800x300" alt="">
                    <div class="caption-full">
                        <h4><a href="#">Artist 1</a>
                        </h4>
                        <p>Want to know when "Artist 1" will next be performing live? CLick this link <a target="_blank" href="#">website here</a>.</p>
                        <p><strong>About "Artist 1"</strong></p>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
              </div>
          </div>
  </div>
```

The issue can only be seen on wider displays and not on mobile sized displays. To put it into context i want the main paragraph to take the left half of the box its in, so i can embed a Spotify playlist in the right hand half of the box.

All help is much appriciated. Happy to buy someone a coffee that can help.

Comment: You have not supplied the `CSS` you're using which will *not* help you get an answer... #hintHint :)

Comment: Hi @jefré-n , thanks for reminding me! I was in a rush last night, should have put some more time into it. I have entered a full code snippet now, appriciated any help that can be offered.

Answer (score 1):

So i figured this out, i needed to add a `<div class="row">` underneath the `<div class="caption-full">` and then use new divs to seperate the left and the right of this new row.

Example of the code that fixed my issue (its not neat yet):

```css
.thumbnail {
  padding: 0;
}
.thumbnail .caption-full {
  padding: 9px;
  color: #333;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">

  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-3">
      <p class="lead">Our Artists</p>
      <div class="list-group">
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item active">Artist 1</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Artist 2</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Artist 3</a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-9">

      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/800x300" alt="">
        <div class="caption-full">
          <div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-7">
          <h4><a href="#">Artist 1</a>
                        </h4>
          <p>Want to know when "Artist 1" will next be performing live? CLick this link <a target="_blank" href="#">website here</a>.</p>
          <p><strong>About "Artist 1"</strong>
          </p>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
            irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p>
            </div>
      <div class="col-md-5">
        <p>irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p>
      </div>
        
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please can someone mark this correct if you believe i have solved this the right way, alternatively happy to know if there is a "better practice" way to do this.

Comment: I'm rather confused. As far as I can tell, the lorem ipsum text is still taking up the whole width of its container ... ? To be perfectly honest, I can't tell what's changed. :(

Comment: Hi @jefré-n, because the code snippet runs in a smaller width screen (like a mobile device) the columns stack (as is expected with the bootstrap grid system "col-md-9"). However if you run this full screen you will see that where before, the lorem ipsum took up the whole width, it now only takes half the width, and the paragraph that was previously below is now to the right. Happy to discuss in more detail if you want!

Comment: I see what you mean now. :) I suggest that you accept your answer so that it shows as fixed.